# How do you replace glass panes in an antique wooden door?

Tags: doors, windows, glass

The middle glass pane is shattered but it isn’t obvious to me how the panes are secured here. Do these routed wood pieces come off? Welcome any suggestions from veterans.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the "backside" picture, the back side molding is the removable one.

[image]

That tiny divot is from the nail, staple, or glazing point holding the molding in place. The "frontside" molding includes the wood that the backside molding is attached to, in normal practice.

Comment: With _very_ careful prying with a putty knife, that piece of trim can be removed. Then remove the other 3 pieces of trim to expose the glass. There may (should) be "glazier's points" holding the glass in. These can also be removed with the putty knife to get the rest of the glass out. "Installation is reverse of removal", I believe is how the auto repair manuals put it... :)

Answer (score 3):

Those pieces do come out but the hard part will be determining which side to remove. Get a utility knife and start cutting into the seams to remove all the old paint. Remove the broken glass so you have an inside edge to pry out with. Sand down the pieces and look for nail holes and pull out the nails. With patience, you should be able to remove them and reinstall them after replacing the glass. If you destroy the pieces in the process, you might find a close match at your home store or lumber yard. You could also go to a cabinet maker and get some custom pieces milled.